# How to eliminate all occurences of a tag?

Tags: xslt

I want to remove a tag from the output with xslt, *by keeping all of its children*. In the example below, I am trying to eliminate all occurences of `<b>`.

Input (with `<b>` tags):

```
<a>
  text
  <b>
    <child/>
    text
  </b>
</a>
```

The expected output should be, after the elimination of the `<b>`s:

```
<a>
  text
  <child/>
  text
</a>
```

Thus, the goal is to keep the children of the `<b>`, by stepping them a level up in the tag hierarchy.

I think some complex template could do that, but is there a simple solution? I am yet in xslt-1.

Comment: How would your "complex" template look? `<xsl:template match="b"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>`? It doesn't get much simpler in my view. Of course, use the identity transformation as the base template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it simply like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="b">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDk3

Comment: OMG, after consulting [this](http://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/) I understood what is your code doing and it was like an explosion in my brain.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Welcome to the world of XSLT! Start thinking in a new way and you'll realize how clever it is!